# delete value from multiple cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

in excel it is possible to delete values of multiple selected cells, how can I achieve this with JTable?

In this sample code, only the value from one cell is deleted.

**Multiple cells selected**

[image]

**Only one the value in one cell is deleted, and it also enters editing mode after the delete button is pressed which I don't want because it is not doing this in excel.**

[image]

**SSCCE**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class table extends JFrame{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    table frame = new table();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public table() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(2)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 422, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        table = new JTable(){
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e){
                boolean result = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
                final Component editor = getEditorComponent();
                if (editor == null || !(editor instanceof JTextComponent)) {
                    return result;
                }
                if (e instanceof KeyEvent) {
                    ((JTextComponent)editor).selectAll();
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column 1", "New column 2", "New column 3", "New column 4", "New column 5", "New column 6"
            }
        ));
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        new PegarExcel(table);
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}


//*********************************************************************************************************
//Clase que se encarga del pegado
//*********************************************************************************************************

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class PegarExcel implements ActionListener{
    private String rowstring,value;
    private Clipboard system;
    private StringSelection stringSelection,stsel;
    private JTable jTable1 ;
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public PegarExcel(JTable myJTable)
    {
    jTable1 = myJTable;

    KeyStroke paste = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,false);

    jTable1.registerKeyboardAction(this,"Paste",paste,JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

    system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public JTable getJTable() {
        return jTable1;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setJTable(JTable jTable1) {
        this.jTable1=jTable1;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void showErrorMessage(String msg){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg,msg,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void pasteAction(){
        system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        try{
            String data= (String)system.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            if(data==null) {
                showErrorMessage("No data on clipboard");
                return;
            }

            int selectCol=jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
            int selectRow=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            if(selectCol<0||selectRow<0) {
                showErrorMessage("Please Select cell");
                return;
            }
            //devuelve clipboard contenido

    StringTokenizer st,stTmp;
    st=new StringTokenizer(data,"\n");
    int pasteRows=st.countTokens ();
    st=new StringTokenizer(st.nextToken ().trim (),"\t");
    int pasteCols=st.countTokens ();
    int marginCols=jTable1.getColumnCount()-selectCol;
    int marginRows=jTable1.getRowCount()-selectRow;
    //revisa espacio disponible
    if(marginCols<pasteCols || marginRows<pasteRows){
        //showErrorMessage("La tabla no posee el espacio suficiente para pegar los datos");
        //return;
    }

    st=new StringTokenizer (data,"\n");
    int rowCount=0,colCount;
    //copia a la tabla
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        stTmp=new StringTokenizer (st.nextToken (),"\t");
        colCount=0;

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        System.out.println("model.getRowCount():"+model.getRowCount());
        System.out.println("rowCount+selectRow:"+(rowCount+selectRow));
        System.out.println("pasteRows:"+(pasteRows));
        System.out.println("marginRows:"+(marginRows));
        System.out.println("rowCount:"+rowCount);

        if(rowCount+selectRow>model.getRowCount()-1){

            if(0==model.getRowCount())
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",1,"MB",10000, true,true,"","",""});
            else
                model.addRow(new Object[]{model.getValueAt(model.getRowCount()-1, 0),"","",1,"MB", 10000, true,true,"","",""});
        }

        while(stTmp.hasMoreTokens ()){
            String columnClassName =jTable1.getColumnClass(colCount+selectCol).getName();
            if("java.lang.String"==columnClassName)
                jTable1.setValueAt(stTmp.nextToken(),rowCount+selectRow,colCount+selectCol);
            else if("java.lang.Integer"==columnClassName)
                jTable1.setValueAt(Integer.parseInt(stTmp.nextToken()),rowCount+selectRow,colCount+selectCol);
            else if("java.lang.Boolean"==columnClassName){
                boolean bool = Boolean.parseBoolean(stTmp.nextToken());
                jTable1.setValueAt(bool,rowCount+selectRow,colCount+selectCol);
            }
            else
                jTable1.setValueAt(stTmp.nextToken(),rowCount+selectRow,colCount+selectCol);

            System.out.println("columnClassName: "+columnClassName);
            //jTable1.setValueAt(stTmp.nextToken(),rowCount+selectRow,colCount+selectCol);
            colCount++;
        }


        rowCount++;
        }
    }

    catch(UnsupportedFlavorException uf){
        System.out.println ("uf="+uf.getMessage ());
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println ("io="+io.getMessage ());
    }

    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand ().compareTo ("Paste")==0){ 
            pasteAction();
        return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand your probelm correctly, you need to attach an appropriate Key Binding to handle your requirements...

For example,

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "delete");
am.put("delete", new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("DeleteMe...");

    }
});
```

Take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

The reason the table is entering "editor" mode probably comes down to how the default editors are setup.  They are accepting <kbd>Delete</kbd> as an initiator for the edit mode

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested,

I followed MadProgrammer's advice and added this code to PegarExcel.java (line 31), it appears to have solved the problem :)

```
    InputMap  im = jTable1.getInputMap();
    ActionMap am = jTable1.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "delete");
    am.put("delete", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] columns = jTable1.getSelectedColumns();
                int[] rows = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
                for(int row:rows){
                    for(int column:columns){
                        jTable1.setValueAt(null,row,column);
                    }
                }

            }
     });
```

Comment: It looks like you're using view coordinates consistently, but you might swap two columns or sort the rows to check.